# Adding a database.properties file in tomcat to store the database properties in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

In my `Spring MVC` web application, I have added a `database.properties` file under the Tomcat folder. Now I am trying to load all the properties from that file as follows: In my `root-contxt.xml` file,

```
<bean 
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value = "file:${catalina.base}/conf/database.properties">
    </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" 
         class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>
```

And in the `database.properties` file, I have,

```
database.driverClassName=my.Driver
database.url=url
database.username=uname
database.password=pwd
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
19:42:10.409 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [spring/core/root-context.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'database.driverClassName' in string value "${database.driverClassName}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'database.driverClassName' in string value "${database.driverClassName}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:211) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:223) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:86) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265) ~[spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:162) ~[spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606) ~[spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462) ~[spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) ~[spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) ~[spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4720) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'database.driverClassName' in string value "${database.driverClassName}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174) ~[spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126) ~[spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer$PlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver.resolveStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:259) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveStringValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:282) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:204) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitPropertyValues(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:141) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:82) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

Is there any way to fix it....

Answer (score 1):

Whatever Path of You are driver you defined in Property File  just Recheck that

Comment: is there any way to verify the path?

Comment: in You are path try to add double cotes or may be u missing some syybols or special characters